# Creating a search query with wildcard in SQL2

Tags: aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I've got a request about a search, using wildcard.

I created the following query

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE
ISDESCENDANTNODE(p, [/home/users/ldap/2]) AND
p.[sling:resourceType] = 'cq/security/components/profile' AND 
Contains (p.memberOf, 'SUG-pilot-anna')
```

and it works as expected. The task of this query is to look for users, who are member of a particular ldap group.

Because there is a lot of work to search for every single group, like

```
SUG-pilot-anna
SUG-pilot-berta
SUG-pilot-ceta
```

, it would be easier and more efficient to use the wildcard. According serveral documantations, the `LIKE` operator is supported by SQL2.

My question is: how does looks the query with wildcard?

Thanks for your help/idears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%` wildcard and query for your requirements.

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE
ISDESCENDANTNODE(p, [/home/users/ldap/2]) AND
p.[sling:resourceType] = 'cq/security/components/profile' AND 
p.memberOf LIKE 'SUG-pilot-%'
```

This would return the list of users who belong to any group name starting with `SUG-pilot-`.
'**%**' matches zero or more characters and '**_**' matches exactly one character.

The exact query which was working in my instance was

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE
ISDESCENDANTNODE(p, [/home/users/]) AND
p.[sling:resourceType] = 'cq/security/components/profile' AND 
p.memberOf LIKE '%de%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it and it generated an empty resultset compare to the first query.

Comment: Am not sure about the ldap profile which you have nor the memberOf property that you are checking for. I tried executing that above query for existing properties and it works. Both contains and like gives me the same result. By the way which version of CQ5 are you using @reporter?

Comment: I am using CQ5.4 and the property 'memberOf' does exists in the profile node from a stored ldap user. As I wrote my query with 'Contains()' does work.

Comment: Maybe `LIKE` does not work, because the values are stored as type of `String[]`.

Comment: i checked LIKE for type String[] and it still returns me results. Not sure why it doesn't work for your query. Can you try '%SUG%' and see if any results are available?

Comment: When I added a percent sign at first position it did works. Thanks for help.